# FIREBASE FOR FLUTTER CodeLab not working on IOS sim

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm pretty new to Flutter and want to add Firebase to my Flutter app. So I went through the Flutter Codelab: 
[enter link description here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#7)

However I am getting errors as soon as I add the Cloud_Firestore package to my Pubspec.yaml file:

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2     # new
```

I continued hoping that a following activity would resolve the problem and created the GoogleService-Info.plist file and added that as instructed.
However I still get the errors and build fail.

Here are the errors:

> Error output from Xcode build: ↳ 2019-01-21 10:19:17.576
>   xcodebuild[70286:12860097] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in
>   compatibility UUID D7881182-AD00-4C36-A94D-F45FC9B0CF85 for plug-in at
>   path '~/Library/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RealmPlugin.xcplugin' not
>   present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs 2019-01-21 10:19:17.577
>   xcodebuild[70286:12860097] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in
>   compatibility UUID D7881182-AD00-4C36-A94D-F45FC9B0CF85 for plug-in at
>   path '~/Library/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present
>   in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
>   ** BUILD FAILED **

Any help with solving this would be really appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the answer. Not sure why it's happening, seems that it's due to a bug in cloud_firestore 0.8.0.

So if anyone else is having this error, do the following:

1. go to terminal, open your apps directory,
2. cd ios
3. pod update Firebase

That should fix it.